# How to club all values of MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, union-all

I am using UNION ALL to club the values.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as votesfromIndia FROM voting WHERE MobNo LIKE '91%'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) as votesfromUS FROM voting WHERE MobNo LIKE '1%'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) as votesfromBelgium FROM voting WHERE MobNo LIKE '32%'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) as votesfromHK FROM voting WHERE MobNo LIKE '852%'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) as votesfromIsrael FROM voting WHERE MobNo LIKE '972%'
```

Result is :

[image]

But I want country wise:

[image]

Fields I am having: name, mobno.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column to each `union`ed query with a constant value that shows the country each row corresponds to:

```
SELECT 'India' country, COUNT(*) as votes FROM tbl_javoting WHERE nMobNo LIKE '91%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'US', COUNT(*) FROM tbl_javoting WHERE nMobNo LIKE '1%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Belgium', COUNT(*) FROM tbl_javoting WHERE nMobNo LIKE '32%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hong Kong', COUNT(*) FROM tbl_javoting WHERE nMobNo LIKE '852%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Israel', COUNT(*) FROM tbl_javoting WHERE nMobNo LIKE '972%'
```

Side note: it is not necessary (nor relevant) to give different names to the columns returned by each `union`ed query: the first query defines the column names for the whole resultset.

Answer (score 0):

I guess name is the country name?

```
SELECT name as Country, COUNT(*) as votes FROM tbl_javoting group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression for aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN MobNo LIKE '91%' THEN 'India'
             WHEN MobNo LIKE '1%' THEN 'US'
             WHEN MobNo LIKE '32%' THEN 'Belgium' 
             WHEN MobNo LIKE '852%' THEN 'HK' 
             WHEN MobNo LIKE '972%' THEN 'Israel'
        END) as location,
        COUNT(*) as votes
FROM voting 
GROUP BY location;
```

If you want the results in separate columns:

```
SELECT SUM(MobNo LIKE '91%') as India, 
       SUM(MobNo LIKE '1%') as US, 
       SUM(MobNo LIKE '32%') as Belgium, 
       SUM(MobNo LIKE '852%') as HK, 
       SUM(MobNo LIKE '972%') as Israel
FROM voting ;
```